# How to parse Videos ID Name Category from Json in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a Json file (video.js) from a http server.
this code is working fine, I get the name and the url ,so the video is playing perfect, but the only problem is I cant get the Video ID or channel number (chid) to show just before the video name.
I also would love to know how to put it in categories like Rock, RNB, POP etc. I tried this with the below json but not working. It only work if I remove categories. sorry I am a total newbie

```
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {// called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                String jsonResponse = new String(response);

                try {


                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    String videoTitle, videoUrl, videoNum ;

                    int length = jsonArray.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                        jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);



                        videoTitle = jsonObject.getString("chname");
                        videoUrl = jsonObject.getString("chlink");
                        videoNum = jsonObject.getString("chid");


                        VideoItem videoItem = new VideoItem(videoTitle, videoUrl, videoNum);
                        videoList.add(videoItem);

                    }
```

My Json file

```
{categories: [
    {
        "chid": 1,
        "chname": "Video 1",
        "chlogo": "",
        "chlink": "http://samplevideo1.mp4",
        "chenable": "",
        "chnote": ""
    },
    {
        "chid": 2,
        "chname": "Video 2",
        "chlogo": "",
        "chlink": "http://samplevideo2.mp4",
        "chenable": "",
        "chnote": ""
    },
    {
        "chid": 3,
        "chname": "RO 3",
        "chlogo": "",
        "chlink": "http://samplevideo3.mp4",
        "chenable": "",
        "chnote":

    }
    ]
    }
```

My adapter

public class VideoSelectionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private List<VideoItem> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public VideoSelectionListAdapter(Context context,List<VideoItem> items) {
    //items = VideoItems.getItems();
    this.items=items;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_text_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simple_text_text_view);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}
```

}

Update
here is my VideoItem

```
public class VideoItem {
String title;
int mediaNum;
String mediaUrl;

public VideoItem(String title, String mediaUrl, int mediaNum) {
    this.title = title;
    this.mediaUrl = mediaUrl;
    this.mediaNum = mediaNum;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public int getMediaNum() {
    return mediaNum;
}
public String getMediaUrl() {
    return mediaUrl;
}
```

Comment: Your parsing code looks fine for the data you are asking for. Whats the problem? Can you please show the adapter code?

Comment: The problem is the chid is not showing like the name, how do I set it as Integer? Sorry as I mentioned I am new to this.

Comment: That's fine. If you try to understand JSON parsing (which is not specific to Android at all), then you'll notice that 1) the id is actually an integer, but your code attempts to get as a string 2) I don't know what you mean by "not showing" because your code doesn't have a [mcve]. You need to show the adapter and the VideoItem object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to display an ID as well as the title, then update this line to do that.

```
holder.text.setText(items.get(position).getTitle())
```

I might also suggest making a variable for the value of `items.get(position)`

```
VideoItem v = items.get(position);
holder.text.setText(v.getMediaNum() + " - " + v.getTitle());
```

Comment: How do I add the ID and the title please I have tried this but didnt work holder.text.setText(items.get(position).getMediaNum ()); no errors but still is not showing any numbers just the name.

Comment: Are you familiar with a thing called string concatenation?

Comment: Not really but I tried to add + , and they didnt work. Is that what you mean by  string concatenation?

Comment: Yes, you should `+` the number and title strings. If you see duplicates of the name, then please check the value that you are returning from the VideoItem class for those methods

Comment: You mean like so holder.text.setText(items.get(position).getTitle + getMediaNum()) ? It didnt work and its red, my value is getMediaNum. Please look at my videoItem, Thanks you for your help by the way

Comment: Firstly `getTitle` is a method, so it needs parenthesis. Secondly, `getMediaNum()` is defined on what object? Hint: call both methods on the same object from the list. Which is why I recommended to store a variable in the last part of my answer

Comment: Man I wish I could mark this as answered but I am new here. The number problem is solved and I really thank you for your wonderful explanation. from your example I learned a bit. Calling both methods on the same line is what I wanted for now, but I will make a row for Video IDs. Finally how do I add the Categories?

Comment: (though, your data contains no mention of a category, so I have no idea how you'd even get that)

Answer (score 0):

"chid" is an Integer not a String

Comment: Yes thanks I have corrected but still missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
int videoNum = jsonObject.getInt("chid");
// if you want to conver this value in String then :
String tempVideoNum=videoNum+"";
```